# MySQL query for current GMT time

Tags: mysql, datetime, gmt, convert-tz

This sounds simple enough but I haven't been able to figure out how to use a simple SELECT statement to return the current time in GMT.

I have been trying to use [CONVERT_TZ()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) to convert NOW() to GMT based on the server time zone and the GMT time zone but for some reason it returns NULL when I put in the text time zones. The only way I get a result is to actually put in the offsets which is getting way too complicated for what should be a really simple operation. Here is what I mean:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@global.system_time_zone,'GMT');
NULL

mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'PST','GMT');
NULL

mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'-08:00','+00:00');
2010-02-13 18:28:22
```

All I need is a simple query to return the current time in GMT. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Note: Use UTC time if you need a universal time reference. It's the real reference, not GMT. The latter changes when daylight saving is on.

Comment: @culebron - Thanks for the suggestion! The question still stands. How then can I use a simple select statement to get the current UTC time?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just use UTC (doesnt get affected with daylight savings time)

```
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP();
```

---

Old Content for reference:

this should work, but with

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'PST','GMT');
```

i got also NULL as result. funny enough the example in the mysql docu also returns null

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz
<strike>seems you found a bug in mysql</strike>. (thanks to +Stephen Pritchard)

you could try:

```
SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE;
SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00';
SELECT NOW();
SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE;
```

ok is not exactly what you wanted (its 4 queries, but only one select :-)

Comment: @Rufinus - Good, I'm not crazy. How can MySQL have a bug in such an important function? The UTC_TIMESTAMP() was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: What if database saves records in UTC and search them using current timezone? at one time timezone in general was gmt -1 and after 6 months  it becomes gmt +1 ??

Comment: GMT doesn't get affected by daylight savings time neither. I think everybody here is looking for `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`, so it's a good idea to move your last line to the top of the answer.

Answer (score 13):

**NO BUG in CONVERT_TZ()**

To use CONVERT_TZ() you need to install the time-zone tables otherwise MySql returns NULL.

From the CLI run the following as root

> # mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql

SEE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Thanks

http://www.ArcanaVision.com (SJP 2011-08-18)

Comment: This worked for me almost everytime, but this time `convert_tz()` returns NULL even after timezone update. strange! and I checked - timezone_xxx tables are full. my server version is 5.0.92, compiled from source (as I always do). Never had this problem before...

Comment: Just found out that after filling the zones table `PST` time zone still does not exist. I read in wikipedia and It looks like that PST is not clear enough for defining a timezone because of daylight saving. Some of the cities use DST some do not. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone#Daylight_time . I used Pacific/Los_Angeles rather than PST (to take DST in account).

Comment: I had to use 'US/Pacific' to get a non-NULL value from convert_tz() on my 5.5.27 database. I found this string by browsing through the mysql.time_zone_name table.

Answer (score 12):

Note:
GMT might have DST
UTC does not have DST

```
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP();
```

I made a cheatsheet here: [Should MySQL have its timezone set to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023978/should-mysql-have-its-timezone-set-to-utc)

Answer (score 7):

The surefire way to fetch the current UTC datetime is:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+0:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing all the answers above and seeing it's unreliable to convert to PST, I just used this:

> DATE_SUB(user_last_login, INTERVAL 7 hour)

Comment: This doesn't account for DST rules.

Answer (score 0):

This should work - I think you are specified your timezone wrong. Using Chicago as example

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'America/Chicago', 'GMT')
```

Comment: To use CONVERT_TZ() you need to install the time-zone tables otherwise MySql returns NULL ! They don't come preinstalled in mysql

Answer (score 0):

When the source server timestamp is unknown but the requirement is for a specific tz do this:

```
select convert_tz(utc_timestamp(),'+05:00','+00:00')
```

This uses CST as an example.
utc_timestamp will guarantee a '+00:00' result no matter where you query it.
The '+05:00' is your desired offset.
This works great when hitting multiple unknown servers and it assures you that you returning result will all be in a common tz result set.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for my time zone which is GMT+6 (Asia/Dhaka TimeZone)

MySQL server is in US. The below worked for me.

SELECT CONVERT_TZ( UTC_TIMESTAMP( ) ,  '+06:00',  '+00:00' )

Answer (score -1):

There is no bug in CONVERT_TZ function. You get NULL because you use time zones names/abbreviations. Mysql does not know what this 'GMT','PST', etc means unless you install mysql.time_zone_name table. However if you use numbers it will always work.

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'America/Chicago', 'GMT');
```

returns NULL

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'-08:00','+00:00');
```

returns 2016-06-24 17:58:33

Comment: For some reason it needs a '+' or '-' in the 'from time zone' param.

mariadb > SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'-08:00','00:00');
returns NULL