# Select current time "now ()"  and convert it to GMT 0

Tags: mysql

I need to convert now() to GMT0.

```
SELECT now();
```

should output current time in GMT0.
Is it possible without changing time zone? And using only one select statement?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL query for current GMT time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258274/mysql-query-for-current-gmt-time)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function [utc_timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp) should do what you want.

```
SELECT utc_timestamp();
```