# Datetime shift in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a DATETIME field named `"event_timestamp"` in MySQL database that has the following value:

```
2014-07-23 12:31:00
```

When I query the database (I use SAILS, waterline ORM is used, specifically find() function), the result object shows the value shifted by "2 hours"

```
results.event_timestamp : Wed Jul 23 2014 14:31:00 GMT+0200 (EEST)
```

How can I handle this, I tried setting timezones in Mysql & Nodejs but to no avail.

Comment: have you looked at CONVERT_TZ()? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258274/mysql-query-for-current-gmt-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not shifted by two hours, it is converted from a timestamp without a time zone to a timestamp with a time zone. When you store dates in a database, they are automatically saved in UTC time, so it is implied that your date

```
2014-07-23 12:31:00
```

is really

```
Wed Jul 23 2014 12:31:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

When you query it using Waterline, it automatically gets converted to your local time zone format, giving you:

```
Wed Jul 23 2014 14:31:00 GMT+0200 (EEST)
```